# Weight added to truck

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, weight

If weight is added to the back of a dump truck does the height of the truck decrease in direct proportion to the weight added - does weight added equal height decrease?

Comment: I don't think this can be usefully answered because it depends on the design of the truck. Vehicle suspension springs do not necessarily have a linear response to load. This is really an engineering problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suspension springs can be linear or non-linear. If the former, then the height of the vehicle will be in direct proportion to the load. If the latter, then the change in height will be less as more weight is added.
 If the weight is added more or less proportionally in front of and behind the rear axil(s), then both the rear and front height will decrease. If the majority or weight is added behind that fulcrum, then the front will rise.
If the weight is added behind the vehicle's center of gravity, both the front and rear height will decrease, with the rear decreasing more than the front, thus causing the appearance of the front rising.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, yes. The springs will have a spring constant.  When you add weight, the height will decrease by the weight times the spring constant.  If you don't add the weight evenly, one end may sink more than the other.  The other end may even rise.

Comment: The other end won't rise unless more than 50% of the weight is added behind the other end's axil (fulcrum).